# how display post on subcategory

Tags: wordpress

I want to display posts in the subcategory but don't know what to do. But this code does not show the post in the category but the entire post in the category.  Can you help me?

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type' => 'hotcheck',
  'topics__in' => array($cat->term_id),
   ) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?> 
    <div class="entry">
      <h2 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  <!-- show pagination here -->
<?php else : ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'hotcheck',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category', // Add your taxonomy name here
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => $cat->term_id,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Hope its work for you Thanks!

Comment: Thks sir but code not working. give me warning " Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\tropic\wp-includes\post-template.php on line 284"

Comment: Please use $count = $query->found_posts to get total row count.